# AddressSanitizer: new-delete-type-mismatch with mysql-connector-c++

Tags: c++, mysql, address-sanitizer

I compiled my code with -fsanitize=address and I get this error:

```
==11760==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: new-delete-type-mismatch on 0x6020000050d0 in thread T5:
  object passed to delete has wrong type:
  size of the allocated type:   8 bytes;
  size of the deallocated type: 1 bytes.
    #0 0x7f25f2aee938 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/libasan.so.4+0xe1938)
    #1 0x7f25f1c94de6 in sql::mysql::MySQL_ParamBind::clearParameters() (/usr/lib64/libmysqlcppconn.so.7+0x6bde6)
    #2 0x7f25f1c8f0f2 in sql::mysql::MySQL_Prepared_Statement::closeIntern() (/usr/lib64/libmysqlcppconn.so.7+0x660f2)
    #3 0x7f25f1c91f5c in sql::mysql::MySQL_Prepared_Statement::~MySQL_Prepared_Statement() (/usr/lib64/libmysqlcppconn.so.7+0x68f5c)
    #4 0x7f25f1c92198 in sql::mysql::MySQL_Prepared_Statement::~MySQL_Prepared_Statement() (/usr/lib64/libmysqlcppconn.so.7+0x69198)
    #5 0x555e98524892 in Job::process_job(sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection*) (/src/build/game_server+0x27c892)
    #6 0x555e9842ecd5 in DbWorker::run_jobs_thread(int) /src/DbWorker.cpp:136
    #7 0x555e984307d2 in DbWorker::run_thread(int) /src/DbWorker.cpp:115
    #8 0x555e98425b94 in void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (DbWorker::*)(int), DbWorker*, int>(std::__invoke_memfun_deref, void (DbWorker::*&&)(int), DbWorker*&&, int&&) /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include/g++-v7/bits/invoke.h:73
    #9 0x555e98425b94 in std::__invoke_result<void (DbWorker::*)(int), DbWorker*, int>::type std::__invoke<void (DbWorker::*)(int), DbWorker*, int>(void (DbWorker::*&&)(int), DbWorker*&&, int&&) /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include/g++-v7/bits/invoke.h:95
    #10 0x555e98425b94 in decltype (__invoke((_S_declval<0ul>)(), (_S_declval<1ul>)(), (_S_declval<2ul>)())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (DbWorker::*)(int), DbWorker*, int> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul, 2ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul, 2ul>) /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include/g++-v7/thread:234
    #11 0x555e98425b94 in std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (DbWorker::*)(int), DbWorker*, int> >::operator()() /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include/g++-v7/thread:243
    #12 0x555e98425b94 in std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (DbWorker::*)(int), DbWorker*, int> > >::_M_run() /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include/g++-v7/thread:186
    #13 0x7f25f16fcf9d  (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/libstdc++.so.6+0xe0f9d)
    #14 0x7f25f1edb979 in start_thread (/lib64/libpthread.so.0+0x7979)
    #15 0x7f25f0df23ee in clone (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x1013ee)

0x6020000050d0 is located 0 bytes inside of 8-byte region [0x6020000050d0,0x6020000050d8)
allocated by thread T5 here:
    #0 0x7f25f2aed3b8 in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/libasan.so.4+0xe03b8)
    #1 0x7f25f1c94272 in sql::mysql::MySQL_Prepared_Statement::setString(unsigned int, sql::SQLString const&) (/usr/lib64/libmysqlcppconn.so.7+0x6b272)

Thread T5 created by T0 here:
#0 0x7f25f2a44b2f in pthread_create (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/libasan.so.4+0x37b2f)
#1 0x7f25f16fd2c4 in std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/libstdc++.so.6+0xe12c4)
#2 0x7ffe077cd9f7  (<unknown module>)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: new-delete-type-mismatch (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/libasan.so.4+0xe1938) in operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
```

The code that generates that is:

```
bool Job::process_job(sql::Connection *c) {
    try {
        std::unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> pstmt;
        std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res;

        pstmt.reset(c->prepareStatement(sql_select1));
        pstmt->setString(1, player_id);
        res.reset(pstmt->executeQuery());
        while (res->next()) {
            // Processing results...
        }

    } catch(sql::SQLException &) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

It seems like it happens when unique_ptr goes out of scope and deletes pstmt.
But what is it? Am I doing something wrong?

I use:

x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-7.3.0

mysql-connector-c++ 1.1.6

glibc 2.26-r7

The most interesting fact, that the same code works fine without problems and memory leaks with the same compile options on system:

x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-7.3.0

mysql-connector-c++ 1.1.6

glibc 2.23-r4

Comment: I've tried to use **delete pstmt** instead of smart pointers and got the same result

Comment: What is the type of player_id?  The issue occurs when freeing up memory for allocated param values and you have only one param.  Also, provide the select string you use, sql_select1.  The problem is related to the memory used to store player_id.

Comment: std::string player_id;

Comment: @SeanF The SQL statement is simple: SELECT * FROM players p LEFT JOIN sessions s ON p.id = s.pid WHERE p.uuid = ? LIMIT 1

Comment: ok, using a std::string and the using that select string looks ok to me.  The warning is at sql::mysql::MySQL_ParamBind::clearParameters() which is code that is deleting data structures allocated for the bind variables, and the one bind variable you have is that uuid string.

Comment: Not clear to me what is going wrong, the source is here: https://github.com/olibre/cmake-tutorial/blob/master/make_tut/mysql-connector-cpp/driver/mysql_prepared_statement.cpp.  The code is casting to char * and I think perhaps the type casting in that source code is causing that warning.  I suspect it is an issue with the mysql code.